# choose an image from gallery Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I was writing a code that enables the users to choose profile pictures from gallery. So far the code is as follows.

(1) In the fields under the activity, I declared a button, an imageview and a static integer.

```
private Button btnChooseProfile;
private ImageView ivProfile;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
```

(2) Now, I make them actually seen in the screen through the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    btnChooseProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChooseProfile);
    ivProfile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);

    btnChooseProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
};
```

(3) And finally, I overrode the onActivityResult method to define what happens after clicking the btnChooseProfile button.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ivProfile.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath));
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, I manage to access the gallery. After choosing the image I would expect that the imageview contains a chosen picture, but somehow the application would just end.

I already have read quite many solutions suggested in the site, and there seems to be no problem with the code snippet itself. If I am missing something, please give me some advice and that will be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

EDIT here's the logcat. (Log level: debug)

```
07-13 15:15:25.961  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo E/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 29
    User space API version: 29
07-13 15:15:25.961  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo E/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Tue Jul 22 19:59:34 KST 2014
07-13 15:15:26.051  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-13 15:15:28.726  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 153K, 6% free 14269K/15064K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
07-13 15:15:28.751  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-13 15:15:28.831  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 6% free 14329K/15088K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
07-13 15:15:28.861  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 33.649MB for 19955728-byte allocation
07-13 15:15:28.876  28110-28119/com.marshall.gruppo D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 33816K/34580K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
07-13 15:15:33.401  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-13 15:15:37.681  28110-28110/com.marshall.gruppo D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
```

Comment: @AnandSingh edited. But the logcat doesn't seem to show much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Bitmap compressImage(String imageUri) {

        String filePath = imageUri;
        // String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not
        // loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
        // you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

        // max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as
        // 816x612

        /*
         * float maxHeight = 816.0f; float maxWidth = 612.0f;
         */
        float maxHeight = 1080.0f;
        float maxWidth = 800.0f;

        float imgRatio = actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        // width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the
        // image

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        // setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of
        // the original image

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth,
                actualHeight);

        // inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        // this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low
        // on memory
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            // load the bitmap from its path
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2,
                middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(
                        Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        // check the rotation of the image and display it properly
        ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } 

            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                    scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                    true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledBitmap;
        }
```

Comment: So basically my code is not working due to the size problem, eh?

Comment: Yes its because of out of memory crash on bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I would not do all of those things you do in onActivityResult... It's the main thread, so accessing the DB (ContentProvider) and decoding the Bitmap is not recommended. Fire up an AsyncTask or something.

Sometimes the returned data is null (yes it happens) - make your code null safe. Add some logs.

I believe you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a big picture size issue. Try this code to reduce the size of your picture.

```
 Bitmap photo;
        File file = new File(picturePath);
        int file_size = Integer
                .parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));
        if (file_size > 2048)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 4;
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        } else if (file_size > 1024)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        } else
            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ivProfile.setImageBitmap(photo);
```